# Single word for "people with premonition"

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call people who have great power of premonition?

Comment: 1. clairvoyant 2. seers 3. psychic

Comment: 4. deluded. 5. charlatans.  Note: question is "What do *you* call them?"

Comment: Cassandras, if they are disbelieved.

Comment: Mediums or fortunetellers.

Answer (score 2):

Psychic is the suitable word to describe people who have great power of premonition. Psychic (noun) is "a person who has a special mental ability, for example being able to know what will happen in the future or what people are thinking" (Source: Cambridge Dictionaries). 
It originated  in early 19th century from Greek "psukhikos" ( Ref: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/psychic).

Answer (score 0):

A sensitive. (from M-W)

- a person having occult or psychical abilities.
- a person with psychic powers; medium.